# How to use XSD 1.1 in Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, xsd, xsd-1.1

Netbeans seems to reject some XSD tags supported by XSD 1.1, for example "assert":

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a : Invalid content found from the element
>   'xs:assert'. One of the values
>   '{"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":attribute,
>   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":attributeGroup,
>   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema":anyAttribute}' is expected. [205]

I tried to use some of [these examples](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter14.html) without success. What can I do to resolve my problem?

As far as I know, I have nothing to do to specify in the XSD schema that I use some features of XSD 1.1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends exactly what you mean by *"use XSD 1.1 in  NetBeans 8.2"*, but I assume you want to use the context menu entry **Validate XML** in NetBeans against some ***.xsd** file with XSD 1.1 features (such as **assert**). If I do that I see the same *"cvc-complex-type.2.4.a : Invalid content found..."* error that you report.

There is no way to customize the validator used by the **Validate XML** command, and apparently it uses the JDK's **javax.xml** API for validation. NetBeans 8.2 uses Java 8, but [even with JDK 9 there is no way to validate XSD 1.1 features](http://schematron.com/2018/04/whats-in-java-10-and-9-for-xml-developers/):

> **Java 9.**
>
> ...The big news is that finally we get the internal ports of Xerces 
>   updated.  Oracle (and Sun before them) have been really slack in
>   neglecting this so long: Java was stuck using Xerces 2.7.n for 11
>   years for goodness sake.  The new ports are equivalent to Apache
>   Xerces 2.11.0. (**NOTE: XSD is still 1.0 only, the XSD 1.1 updates have
>   not been put in place**, but this probably reflects Apache Xerces’ slow
>   pace to make the changes official.)

The same problem occurs when using [Apache NetBeans 9.0 RC1](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html) so this issue will probably not get resolved until either:

- NetBeans uses a JDK which uses a version of Xerces that supports the validation of XSD 1.1 features.
- NetBeans uses a different approach for XSD validation.

I also don't see any NetBeans plugins that will help. Of course there are still third-party tools and (possibly) configuration for Maven projects that may help, but I don't see a solution using only NetBeans.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I want to use the context menu entry Validate XML in NetBeans and "schemavalidate" in Apache Ant. Apache Xerxes Java 2.12.0 supports XSD 1.1. I'll have to wait :(